# Multiline Label within UITableViewCell not working with iOS 9 or Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to have a multi-line label within a table view cell. I have tested the code below on iOS 8 and it works fine and the text within the cell is has the correct number of lines.

```
// Make row heights adjustable
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
multiLineCell.indentationWidth = 10.0

multiLineCell.text = "Hello, here is some text which needs to be broken down into multiple lines in order for it to be displayed."
```

I cannot visually specify the height because the label's content changes. How would I go about making the cell label display all of its contents with multiple lines within iOS 9 and Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified any of your constraints (there also could be a problem, you need to have explicit constraints set for the whole cell height), but I suspect the problem could be in

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: I have a static table view and programatically populate the label. I had it working fine on iOS 8.